# tool to stress test a classic asp web app

Tags: asp-classic, automation, automated-tests, stress-testing

I'm looking for an open source tool to stress test a classic asp web application

I think it should be something like several selenium tests to be run concurrently...

The application works with a sql database, and it has a public (usernam and password protected) and a private (windows integrated security) front-end

any suggestion?

Comment: jMeter might be worth checking out - http://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can check ASP Profiler http://aspprofiler.sourceforge.net/#Usage